# Create a div exactly where a click is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a div exactly where a click is submitted, below is my attempt but nothing is happening. Can someone please tell me why please?

html:

```
<div id="commentArea"></div>
<div id="commentBox"></div>
```

js:

```
var commentBox = $('#commentBox');  
var offset = -10;   
var posX, posY  
var boxCount = 0;

commentBox.click(function(e){
    $('#commentArea').append('<div class="box-' + boxCount + '"></div>');
    $('.box-' + boxCount).offset({
        top: posY,
        left: posX
    });
    boxCount++;     
});
```

css:

```
#commentBox,
[class^=box] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 60;
    float: left;
}

[class^=box] {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide live demo on jsfiddle/stack-snippet

Comment: The first problem is that you are appending text, so the div you are appending is not part of the DOM. You need to add it into the DOM and then you can access the div via '.box-etc...'

Comment: Define exactly.  Exactly on the screen so scrolling doesn't affect it (fixed) exactly relative to other elements or the window?

Comment: "Something" is actually happening, but the divs are empty! Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/o5ohc8r3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a child div where the mouse is clicked in the parent (light blue) div.  The child's top left corner will be where the mouse was clicked, but you can adjust that by accounting for the height and with of the new child if you wanted.

```js
document.getElementById("landingPad").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("addedDiv");
  newDiv.style.left = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft + "px";
  newDiv.style.top = event.clientY - this.offsetTop  + "px";
  
  this.appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

```css
#landingPad {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  position: relative;
}

.addedDiv {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="landingPad"></div>
```

Comment: It have problem. Click on added box.

Answer (score 1):

Your code not set value for `posX` and `posY`.

Try this JavaScript. After, change as you wnat.

```
var commentBox = $('#commentBox');  
var offset = -10;   
var posX = 10, posY = 10;
var boxCount = 0;

commentBox.click(function(e){
    $('#commentArea').append('<div class="box-' + boxCount + '">' + boxCount + '</div>');
    $('.box-' + boxCount).offset({
        top: posY * boxCount,
        left: posX * boxCount
    });
    boxCount++;     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hanlet explained. Something is happening if you look at the DOM.

Now you can also force it to visualize some of the elements, you will see whats happening.

[Check out what I did here](https://jsfiddle.net/09c1xda3/)

I changed

```
$('#commentArea').append('<div class="box-' + boxCount + '"></div>');
```

to

```
$('#commentArea').append('<div id="box-' + boxCount + '" class="box"></div>');
```

so it's class is the same and it can be visualized as well as some CSS. The id attribute is what is dynamic.